# How to Create Stuts2 Project using Maven

Tags: java, apache, maven, struts2, struts

In the [official doc by Apache Struts](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/how-to-create-a-struts2-web-application.html#java-requirements), they mentioned this:

> "In your Java IDE create a Java web application with a project name of
>   basic_struts that follows the standard Maven project folder structure"

**What does that mean?**

1. Does it mean, create a Maven project? (but that doesn't seemlike a web project)
2. Create a Dynamic Web Project? (But how do I use Maven? I'll be using a `pom.xml` file as mentioned in the guide)

How to create Struts 2 application using Maven?

Comment: It's a Maven web project--I'm not entirely sure what the confusion is; if you're having an issue w/ a specific IDE you'd need to say what IDE you're using (Eclipse?), but in the long run, it's a web project whose dependencies are managed by Maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create struts2 project by choosing this archetype

```
org.apache.struts:struts2-archetype-starter
```

You can get more information about [Maven archetypes](https://struts.apache.org/maven-archetypes/) on the struts site.

> The Starter Archetype (struts2-archetype-starter)
>   The Starter archetype creates a more featured application using several common technologies used in production applications.
>
> **Features**
>
> Sitemesh integration
>
> Action example (instantiated both through Spring and Struts)
>
> Spring integration
>
> Validation example (action and action-alias level)
>
> Conversion example (global and action level)
>
> Resource bundle (both global, action and package level)
>
> `mvn archetype:generate -B -DgroupId=com.mycompany.mysystem \
>                               -DartifactId=myWebApp \
>                               -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.struts \
>                               -DarchetypeArtifactId=struts2-archetype-starter`

Answer (score 1):

Create a dynamic web project and then convert it to maven project in eclipse IDE.

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4jSA.png][1]